# R, keywork extraction using textrank - error ConstructTextGraph

Tags: r, text, keyword, extract

I want to extract keywords from text and then draw a network based on its weight. I got an error at ConstructTextGraph:

```
library(NLP)
library(tm)
library(openNLP)
corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(doc))
corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)
corp <- tm_map(corp, tolower)
words_with_punctuation <- SplitText(as.character(corp[[1]]))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
words <- SplitText(as.character(corp[[1]]))
tagged_text <- tagPOS(corp[[1]])
tagged_words <- SplitText(as.character(tagged_text))
tagged_words <- c(SelectTaggedWords(tagged_words,"/NN"),SelectTaggedWords(tagged_words,"/JJ"))  
tagged_words <- RemoveTags(tagged_words)                                                        
selected_words <- unique(tagged_words)                                                          

text_graph <- ConstructTextGraph(4)

Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
“graphNEL” is not a defined class
```

It used to work fine before, anyone please shows me where was i wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the textrank (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=textrank) R package alongside the udpipe R package (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=udpipe)

The examples in the vignettes of these 2 packages show exactly what you are trying to accomplish.